# cannot invoke 'dequeReusable...' with an argument of type '(String)'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.funlists[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

> cannot invoke 'dequeReusable...' with an argument of type '(String)'
>   on line         var cell:UITableViewCell =
>   self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as
>   UITableViewCell

(sorry i'm extremely new to Xcode and swift)
when i click my UITableView in my storyboard, it is a table view cell with style Subtitle and identifier cell. (I may be doing this completely wrong, not sure)

Comment: var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

Comment: define cell indentifier in storyboard

Comment: @Memon, thanks I have defined the cell identifier in the storyboard. When I change the line of code to what you provided, i get the error: cannot invoke 'dequeReusable...' with an argument of type '(String, forIndexPath: NSindexPath)' on line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find the problem, try to take the word `self` of the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call, like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.funlists[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

The reason been that you want to use the tableView coming from the function and not the tableView that belongs to the class.

Let me know if this solve your problem

Comment: @moez05 that is because returns a AnyObject and swift does not know for sure if it will be convertible to UITableViewCell, putting the ! you are forcing the conversion at the price that if you wrong the application will crash, however in this case you can use for sure as this function always return a UITableViewCell, I am not sure why apple put an AnyObejct as return type here.

Answer (score 1):

Please define your cell identifier in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: it seems as if i have already done this but the error continues to remain

Comment: Check this post in swift for table view - https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/#